# how to start my App in a particular time of the Day in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have an App built on Swift, I want this App to start every day at some particular time. Logically its like Calendar notification, which gives notification in that particular window whatever we set.

Does is the same scenario is possible with an App in iOS  Swift.

Comment: check Background Mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can probably do is to create a local notification, but this is not opening your app. A local notification is just a way to show a notification on your iPhone and then, if the user taps, it's opening your app.

See more here: https://www.codebeaulieu.com/49/How-to-add-local-notifications-to-your-app

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do, you cannot force your application upon the user without the user's consent. What you can do is schedule a local notification so the user knows when to open your app like jomafer proposed already. Also possible is to wake up the app to do stuff in the background:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

For example a silent push notification that will trigger some code, or a scheduled background download.

**NONE OF THESE METHODS ARE 100% RELIABLE THOUGH!**